# MySQL 5.5 - fill gaps with value from above

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing global sales data at different reporting dates like this:

```
+------------+------+------------+---------+
| Closed     | Open | Plan       | Station |
+------------+------+------------+---------+
| 2018-10-23 | NULL | NULL       | A       |
| 2018-10-22 | NULL | NULL       | NULL    |
| 2018-10-22 | NULL | NULL       | B       |
| 2018-10-22 | NULL | NULL       | NULL    |
| NULL       | NULL | 2018-10-23 | C       |
| NULL       | NULL | 2018-10-22 | NULL    |
| NULL       | NULL | 2018-10-22 | NULL    |
+------------+------+------------+---------+

CREATE TABLE Orders
(Closed DATE, 
Open DATE,
Plan DATE,
Station Char);


insert into Orders values ("2018-10-23",NULL,NULL, "A");    
insert into Orders values ("2018-10-22",NULL,NULL, NULL);    
insert into Orders values ("2018-10-22",NULL,NULL, "B");    
insert into Orders values ("2018-10-22",NULL,NULL, NULL);    
insert into Orders values (NULL,NULL,"2018-10-23", "C");
insert into Orders values (NULL,NULL,"2018-10-22", NULL);
insert into Orders values (NULL,NULL,"2018-10-22", NULL);
```

And I want to fill Station Column with the last know value to get the below desired results.

```
+------------+------+------------+---------+
| Closed     | Open | Plan       | Station |
+------------+------+------------+---------+
| 2018-10-23 | NULL | NULL       | A       |
| 2018-10-22 | NULL | NULL       | A       |
| 2018-10-22 | NULL | NULL       | B       |
| 2018-10-22 | NULL | NULL       | B       |
| NULL       | NULL | 2018-10-23 | C       |
| NULL       | NULL | 2018-10-22 | C       |
| NULL       | NULL | 2018-10-22 | C       |
+------------+------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Does the posted answer work ? Please give feedback. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is a Primary Key column (let's say `id`) in your table, which can be used to define the "last known" value of `Station`. **Remember** that data is stored in unordered fashion, and without defining a particular order and/or Primary key, we cannot really define the "last known" value.

[`Coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function will be used to handle `null` value for `Station` in a particular row. Then, we can use [Correlated Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html) to determine the "last known" value.

```
SELECT 
  t1.Closed, 
  t1.Open, 
  t1.Plan, 
  COALESCE(t1.Station, 
           (SELECT t2.Station 
            FROM Orders AS t2 
            WHERE t2.id < t1.id 
              AND t2.Station IS NOT NULL 
            ORDER BY t2.id DESC 
            LIMIT 1)) AS Station 
FROM Orders AS t1
```

**Result**

```
| Closed     | Open | Plan       | Station |
| ---------- | ---- | ---------- | ------- |
| 2018-10-23 |      |            | A       |
| 2018-10-22 |      |            | A       |
| 2018-10-22 |      |            | B       |
| 2018-10-22 |      |            | B       |
|            |      | 2018-10-23 | C       |
|            |      | 2018-10-22 | C       |
|            |      | 2018-10-22 | C       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aHGsWkGnjsV66Fo5svyqww/0)